# Angular 5 testing Karma Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Im trying to test a component but I am getting the following error:

MensajeCancelacionComponent > should create
Failed: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Here is my code for **component code**:

```
export class ButtonsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() environmentBrand;
  @Input() moduleData;
  @Output()
  ClickMe = new EventEmitter<any>();
  datosUsuario;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getModuleData();
  }

  getModuleData() {
    this.datosUsuario = new ModuleData(this.moduleData);
  }
}
```

Currently my **test** looks like so:

```
describe('MensajeCancelacionComponent', () => {
  let component: ButtonsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ButtonsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ButtonsComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ButtonsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.moduleData = {
      textList: [
        {
          description: '',
          key: 'of.your.rate',
          value: 'de tu tarifa'
        }
      ]
    };
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  // it('should create', () => {
  //   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  // });

  it('should create', async(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
  }));
});
```

here is the html template

```
<div *ngIf="datosUsuario" class="text-center pt-6">
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-success text-center btn-normal mr-5"
    (click)="cerrar()"
  >
    {{ datosUsuario.texts.close.value }}
  </button>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-success text-center btn-normal ml-5"
    (click)="cancelar()"
  >
    {{ datosUsuario.texts['want.cancel'].value }}
  </button>
</div>
```

I think the problem could be in the model I use for  the to get the data from moduleData

```
class ModuleText {
  // Clave única del texto
  key: string;
  // Texto a poner
  value: string;
  // Descripción del texto
  description: string;

  constructor(textJSON) {
    this.key = textJSON.key;
    this.value = textJSON.value;
    this.description = textJSON.description;
  }
}
```

Comment: The error could come from a child component. Could you add the template code of your component?

Comment: In your component you have `new ModuleData(this.moduleData)` and yet give example of `class ModuleText`. If these are intended to be the same then yes the model you pass in doesn't match what will be parsed and you would see nulls.